# How can I center float elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can i center the float element that you can see in this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02GUV.jpg)? I want to bring it from the left of the web page to the middle, but keeping it at the top of the page?

Here is the code of the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Batch File Generator | Home</title>
    </head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <ul>
         <li><a>Home</a></li>
         <li><a>Download</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="32-bit version.exe" download="download">32-bit version</a></li>
                 <li><a href="64-bit version.exe" download="download">64-bit version</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a>Discussion</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><a>Community forums</li></a>
                 <li><a>Ask the developers</li></a>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a>News</a></li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

And here is the code of the CSS:

```
body{
    background: url("background.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
}
ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why would you float it to the left when you want to center it? Remove floating and add `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Thanks. "I have to write this otherwise i can't publish the comment 'cos it is too short..."

Comment: Dawid Zbinski It didn't work because it's a drop-down menu and using "margin: 0 auto;" the white writing is, yes in the middle at the top of the page, but it is aligned verticaly and the drop-down effect doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

For HTML Code, use this:

```
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="middle-content">
      <ul>
     <li><a>Home</a></li>
     <li><a>Download</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="32-bit version.exe" download="download">32-bit version</a></li>
             <li><a href="64-bit version.exe" download="download">64-bit version</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Discussion</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a>Community forums</a></li>
             <li><a>Ask the developers</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>News</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

For css code:

```
    html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: url("background.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.middle-content{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%;
}
ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @ange make html and body `height: 100%` and use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`
Follow the answer. You will get the solution.

Comment: I meant if the drop-down menu could appear at the top of the page in the middle. With your code it went from the top to the middle of the page and stayed at the left.

Comment: Do you want to keep the menu middle on the top?

Comment: If you want to make the center menu, you have to use these code
`.middle-content{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 100%;
}
ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: Enamul Haque Thanks, as soon as I can try it I'll tell you the results.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with flexbox.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: thin solid lightgray;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.main-menu li:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.main-menu li:hover>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Download</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="32-bit version.exe" download="download">32-bit version</a></li>
        <li><a href="64-bit version.exe" download="download">64-bit version</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Discussion</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Community forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ask the developers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>News</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```